# Windows 8.1 Update - PCs on my local network

Tags: windows-update, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-10-preview

In Windows 10, one is able to perform windows update from the local network (obviously provided that the updates are available):

[image: Windows Update - PCs on my local network]

Is this possible on Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is a feature specifically introduced by Windows 10.